# How to add a context menu to a supertabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, dotnetbar

I'm using `DotNetBar` component `SuperTabControl`, and I want to display the context menu if the user right click a tab, I found the following code but the problem is my `SuperTabControl` doesn't have the GetTabRect function.

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.superTabControl1.Tabs.Count; ++i)
                {
                    Rectangle r = this.superTabControl1.GetTabRect(i);
                    if (r.Contains(e.Location))
                    {
                       //display menu 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sounds like a question for DevComponents.

Comment: Maybe but I think we can ask here any question :)

Comment: My point is that you'll get better answers there.  They made it.  Here, you have to hope you run into an experienced user.  But, whatever...

Comment: I get your point, you are totally right,but I need an answer in short time so I have to use any way possible to get it, thank you for your advice it really helpful.

Comment: Is there a property such as `this.superTabControl1.Tabs[0].Bounds`?  Since you're just looking for a hit box.

Comment: No there isn't such as property :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there is no answer for my question, I used this code in order to manage closing tabs basing on selected option on my context menu.
To close all the tabs except the seelcted one I used this code.

```
for (int i = this.superTabControl1.Tabs.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                BaseItem item = this.superTabControl1.Tabs[i];
                if (!item.Equals(this.superTabControl1.SelectedTab))
                {
                    (item as SuperTabItem).Close();
                }
            }
```

To close all the tabs.

```
 for (int i = this.superTabControl1.Tabs.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                BaseItem item = this.superTabControl1.Tabs[i];
                (item as SuperTabItem).Close();
            }
```

To close the selected Tab I used this code:

```
this.superTabControl1.SelectedTab.Close();
```